# Why is the number of the conjugacy classes of $D_4 \rtimes Aut(D_4)$ $16$?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups, semidirect-product

Currently, I am reading [Representation Theory of Semi-Direct Products](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-13/2/281.extract) by Reyes.

In section $6$, the author mentions that the number of the conjugacy classes of $D_4 \rtimes Aut(D_4)$ is $16$. My question is why $16$?

I don't even know where to start.

Comment: If it helps with searching, the group $G \rtimes \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is called the *holomorph* of $G$; so you want to know about the holomorph of dihedral groups (something I know nothing about, personally).

Comment: Since I'd like to know more about these things, I'm giving it a shot. I'm starting by figuring out what $\operatorname{Aut}(D_4)$ is (the internet knows) to find the order of $\operatorname{Hol}(G)$; then, I'd like to know what the inverse of $(g, \varphi) \in \operatorname{Hol}(G)$ is so I can start conjugating. I'm sure there are results about $\operatorname{Hol}(G)$, but in lieu of knowing such things, one can always compute -- it's pretty interesting so far.

Comment: @pjs36, well, $Aut(D_n) = C_n \rtimes_\phi Aut(C_n)$.